# Why is the <mat-table> without a Datasource not displayed in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I want to use a `<mat-table>` to display the name of an option and it's corresponding given value (for the user to change). Since the options may need to have their values set by different means (such as a slide-toggle or a mat-selection), I have to write this down without a Datasource (or at least as far as I could find, one can not use prewritten html tags in the typescript file).

Therefore, my MWE would be this:

```
<mat-table>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef>
        <mat-header-cell>header</mat-header-cell>
    </mat-header-row>

    <mat-row>
        <mat-cell>
             cell
        </mat-cell>
    </mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

However, when I look at my page, it just displays a line without any strings. I want to use this table within a `<mat-card>` (or rather `<mat-card-content>`), but even if I try it outside that, I just get the line and nothing else. This is what it looks like within the mat card:

[image: Blank Line]

How can I correctly display the table?

---

***Edit: ***
Since it was asked for, here is also the .ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-general',
  templateUrl: './general.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./general.component.scss']
})
export class GeneralComponent implements OnInit {


  @ViewChild('resolutionSelect') resolutionSelect: MatSelect;

  resolutions: ResolutionOptionsInterface[] = [
    { value: '1920 x 1080' },
    { value: '800 x 600' }
  ];
  public selectedRes = this.resolutions[0];
  public isFullscreenEnabled = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("in oninit");
    this.resolutionSelect.value = this.resolutions[0].value;
  }

}
```

This is a bit more than the minimal working example, so I'll explain a bit:

- One of my options is the resolution, which is choosable by a `mat-select`
- This `mat-select` is described defined in the html file as below
- This `mat-select` will be given pre-defined values, as defined in the `resolutions` array
- Another of my options is simply the choice of fullscreen, making it a `mat-slide-toggle` (however, this is not yet fully implemented)

  `<mat-select #resolutionSelect fxFlex="200px">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let res of resolutions" [value]="res.value" class="right">
          {{res.value}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>`

Comment: you should put ts code to your question too

Comment: So, you want to display the table, but without the data source?

Comment: I will add .ts code, although I don't really see the benefit. Yes, I want to display the table, but there is no data source, since I have to build it by hand: I can't store all possible input possibilities in an external table.

Comment: Ok, and are the `matHeaderRowDef` known at the point of initialisation of the component? Also, you didnt seem to include the `mat-cell`s?

Comment: @wentjun Yes, basically it's just "Option" and "Value" as the header. The `mat-cell`s are there though (or at least the one for the minimal example)

Comment: Ah I see, ok i saw it. Let me get this striaght. When the user selects an option from `mat-select`, the selected value will be displayed on the table (??).

Comment: In the mat-select. Imagine the settings in a game: you have a list of different options. Resolution you can choose by a mat-select. Fullscreen you can choose by a mat-slide-toggle. Gamma you can choose by a text input field etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In fact, it is possible to create a material table without a datasource.
You need to make sure you made the header definitions with displayed columns and all.

Example - html file:

```
<table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="someValue">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Some Value Header</th>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="someOtherValue">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      Some Other Value Header
    </th>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

inside ts file, you need to have defined your array

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['someValue', 'someOtherValue'];
```

**Edit:**
If your requirement is just a simple table with a couple of predefined values, you can achieve it by using native table element with material css classes:

```
<table class="mat-table" >
  <tr class="mat-header-row">
    <th class="mat-header-cell">A</th>
    <th class="mat-header-cell">B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="mat-row">
    <td class="mat-cell">A</td>
    <td class="mat-cell">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see, how I can individually add rows and cells this way. 1. Do i have to add `*matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumsn"` to every row? 2. I have tried with just that one row, and added `<mat-cell>A</mat-cell><mat-cell>B</mat-cell>` into that row, yet still nothing is displayed (although it is visible that there should be something, due to the `mat-elevation-z8` I guess)

Comment: Where is the ngFor?

Comment: The material CSS classes seem to have changed in Angular Material v15...

Answer (score 0):

Since the classes seem to have changed, here is another approach:
Just use `[dataSource]="[{}]"`:

The code in Angular 16 looks like this:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="[{}]">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="person1">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Person 1</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">Alice</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="person2">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Person 2</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">Bob</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Number</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">123</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['person1', 'person2', 'number']"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['person1', 'person2', 'number'];"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

No Typescript or CSS needed.